# OpenReadAsync returns ex Access to the path is denied with sharing target xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, file-sharing, ios-extensions

I'm implementing sharing target in my Xamarin.iOS project.

All the described behavior works on simulator, but fails on real device.

The OpenReadAsync function is already used and working when I select the file via the FilePicker (file type is FileResult):

```
var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(allowedFileTypes);
using Stream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
```

But if I try to create the FileResult manually with the path I get from the sharing target:

```
FileResult file = new FileResult(filePath);
using Stream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
```

I get those 2 exceptions:

- Shared from gallery:

```
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/EF8C049F-C529-44DB-B6FD-3CC6B3ED189D/IMG_0003.JPG".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAc…}
```

- Shared from Files:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0B20B6FA-C27F-4487-9719-D877CAD58452/File Provider Storage/Downloads/IMG_0003.JPG" is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.…}
```

Same behavior if I use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)`

The manually created file obviously miss some access right and the simulator isn't that restrictive as a real device.

But I cannot figure out how to read bytes from a file from just the path given by the sharing extension without using the FilePicker which gives the needed access rights.

I also tried doing the conversion to bytes on the iOS side using

```
NSUrl nSUrl = new NSUrl(cleanUri);
nSUrl.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
var data = NSData.FromUrl(nSUrl);
```

But `NSData.FromUrl` always returns `null`.

Comment: when you use the `FilePicker`, the user is explicitly granting your app the rights to access the file

Comment: So how does apps like whatsapp etc work with sharing target without asking for rights very time? My app does ask for photo access with the photo filepicker once, but it's not changing sharing behavior

Comment: 1. Why do you create `FileResult file = new FileResult(filePath);` , what is `filePath`? 2. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=ios#pick-file), you may need to use `FilePicker.PickAsync(options)` like  `var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);` and then specify the options parameter:specific comic file types. 3. Have you enabled iCloud capabilities in the file picker on iOS?See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/document-picker#enabling-icloud-in-xamarin

Comment: 1. I already use FileResult in the app in the cases where FilePicker is opened. So tried to recreate the same system. Also tried with File.ReadAllBytes(filePath) but same result: denied in real device, gets the bytes fine on simulator. filePath is the AbsoluteString or the file url returned by the SharingExtension.    2. I do not need to open the FilePicker, the file should be read by the app when it opens.   3. How is it cloud related? The file comes from the device and is used locally.

Comment: filePath looks something like this: "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/0B20B6FA-C27F-4487-9719-D877CAD58452/File%20Provider%20Storage/Downloads/IMG_0003.JPG". Appgroups is activated for the project